# Python Flask SQLalchemy Foreign key isn't saved in database - One to Many

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-key-relationship

So I have a form where a user can submit a room, ofcourse a user should be able to submit multiple rooms, but the rooms all belong to this user, so we have a one-to-many relation here (for understanding):

room1 - foreignkey(user1)
room2 - foreignkey(user1)

**The problem:**

When submiting the form, the database recognizes that there is a foreignkey function but the users_id is empty, but there should be the actual id of the user who submited the room.

[image]

**The code:**

I try to show only relevant pieces

Here are my models:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # foreign key
    addresses = relationship('Zimmer', back_populates="users")

class Zimmer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'zimmer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # foreign key
    users_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    users = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")
```

That is the code which populates the database:

```
@app.route("/zimmer_einstellen", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@check_confirmed
def zimmer_einstellen():
    form = ZimmerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_zimmer = Zimmer(art=form.art.data, personen=form.personen.data,              preis=form.preis.data, infofeld=form.infofeld.data, land=form.land.data, bundesland=form.bundesland.data,
                    stadt=form.stadt.data, strasse=form.strasse.data, hausnr=form.hausnr.data, haustiere_erlaubt=form.haustiere_erlaubt.data,
                    bettwaesche_wird_gestellt=form.bettwaesche_wird_gestellt.data, grill_vorhanden=form.grill_vorhanden.data, safe_vorhanden=form.safe_vorhanden.data, kuehlschrank_vorhanden=form.kuehlschrank_vorhanden.data, rauchen_erlaubt=form.rauchen_erlaubt.data, 
                    parkplatz_vorhanden=form.parkplatz_vorhanden.data, kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden=form.kochmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.data, restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden=form.restaurant_im_haus_vorhanden.data, handtuecher_werden_gestellt=form.handtuecher_werden_gestellt.data, tv_vorhanden=form.tv_vorhanden.data, 
                    waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden=form.waschmoeglichkeit_vorhanden.data, wlan_vorhanden=form.wlan_vorhanden.data)

    if new_zimmer:
        db_session.add(new_zimmer)
        db_session.commit()

        flash('Zimmer wurde erfolgreich eingestellt')
        return redirect(url_for('zimmer_einstellen'))
    else:
            flash('Etwas ist schief gelaufen mit dem Einstellen des Zimmers')
return render_template('zimmer_einstellen.html', form=form)
```

But as far as I understand it should be enough to create the foreign key relation and that should be it.

Or do I have to use something like an additional hidden tag in the actual form in html, here is generally what I use (without all the other inputs):

```
<form id="regi" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('zimmer_einstellen', next=request.args.get('next')) }}">
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<div class="form-group">
   {{ form.art.label }} 
   {{ form.art(size=30, class = "form-control") }} 
</div>


 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Zimmer einstellen </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have not created a Zimmer object with a proper users_id:
You need to do something like this:

```
new_zimmer = Zimmer(..., users_id=user_id)
```

And since you don't have access to the users_id, you need to get it. One option as you mentioned is putting it in your html as a hidden input and getting it in **zimmer_einstellen** function.

UPDATE: From your *User* declaration I guess you're using the Flask-Login extension which provides a *current_user* in your application. If that's the  case, you can use *current_user.id* in your views to get the current user's id.

Comment: ah okay this helps me to understant what I could try, I have a few ideas now!

Comment: So I have to move users_id into the __init__ from the Zimmer model right?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it by putting self.users_id = user_id in __init__ of the Zimmer model. But as you know, you should pass the users_id to Zimmer every time you create a zimmer object.

Comment: Yeah thats what I have done. I moved the users_id to init, so I have self.users_id = users_id. And then before creating the Zimmer object, I used users_id = current_user.id. And the last argument of the Zimmer object was then users_id = users_id. Thanks, this works.

Comment: I'm glad to be of help.

Comment: But actually I could have achieved that result without declaring foreign keys... that is what I am questioning

Comment: How would you then decide which Zimmer belongs to which User? I mean you (may in the future) need to know the owner of Zimmers if they are permanent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114245/discussion-between-mohammad-amin-and-roman).